# What can I use to describe a world that only exists between others

Tags: phrases, synonyms

It's for a story that I'm writing. There are many realms connected by a web, and on the webbing a new realm has been created, but I can't call it a realm because it isn't independent. It exists only between others, and isn't whole by any means, yet it's a world people do pass through and live in.

How might I describe this place in a word or phrase?

Comment: A meta-realm...

Comment: It is your story so you can call it anything you like - perhaps 'domain', 'dominion', 'new world'?

Comment: @Stefan Doesn't that make it POB? And doesn't that mean it should be close-voted?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not so interested in closing questions. I find almost all kinds of language discussions interesting. But you are right in that this question probably does not have a right answer. You could give the OP the benefit of doubt here.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine has pointed out the word 'nexus' which encapsulates the meaning I was trying to convey. A link between things that exists as a place but only because of it's connections.

Comment: 'Realm' is a combo of 'royal' and 'regime[n]'.  A web connects 'nodes' (cf. knot), and a nexus (meaning bound together) is either a special node or the system of connected nodes.  'Nexus' sounds like a good word for this story.  Will you pluralize it?